# Using Nominal Roles for Type Inference

Tags: haskell, ghc

I have a `newtype` with a phantom type, but I'm having trouble making easy use of it.

Consider the following example:

```
import Data.Coerce

newtype F a b = F b

myzip :: (Num b) => F a b -> F a b
myzip = (coerce (+)) myf

myf :: F a b
myf = undefined
```

GHC complains that it `Couldn't match representation of type ‘a0’ with that of ‘Int’`. Basically, the type of `coerce (+)` is `F a0 -> F a -> F a`, rather than the type I want, which is `F a -> F a -> F a`.

Given `a`'s current role of `phantom`, this is reasonable. I'm wondering if there's a simple way to get type inference (I don't want to have to write out signatures, that's why I'm using `coerce` in the first place!) by some other method.
In particular, I expected that if I restricted the role of the parameter `a` to nominal, then GHC would be able to tell that the only possible choice for the signature was the one I wanted. No such luck: GHC gives the same error.

In the event it matters, in my real code the role of `a` must be at least representational, and `b` must be nominal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's start by looking at a few types:

```
coerce (+) :: (Num n, Coercible (n -> n -> n) b) => b
myf :: F c d
```

The first problem is that GHC has no hope of pinning down `n` so it can choose an implementation of `(+)`.

Let's see what happens if we use scoped type variables to attempt a simple solution:

```
myzip :: forall a b . Num b => F a b -> F a b
myzip = coerce ((+) :: b -> b -> b) myf
```

This is not accepted. Why? Because the type of `myf` is ambiguous! We can see this more clearly if we expand out `myzip` with another argument:

```
myzip x = coerce ((+) :: b -> b -> b) myf x
```

From the way `Coercible` works with type constructors (`->`, in this case), we can line everything up and conclude that the type of `myf` must be coercible with `b`, where `x :: F a b`. But the type of `myf` in this context is ambiguous. GHC therefore has no way to select the appropriate `Coercible` instance between `b` and a type for `myf`. Because `coerce` is really the identity function under the hood, it doesn't *matter* which one is chosen, but GHC simply won't choose an instance based on an ambiguous type variable. To make this work, you need something like

```
myzip :: forall a b . Num b => F a b -> F a b
myzip = (coerce ((+) :: b -> b -> b)) (myf :: F a b)
```

#### Type roles

Type roles cannot (at least at present) guide instance resolution in any way. All they can do is determine what `Coercible` instances are *generated*. Given

```
class c => X d
```

GHC will conclude that `X d` entails `c`. But given

```
instance c => X d
```

GHC will *not* conclude that `X d` entails `c`. I'm not sure of the details of why, but that has always been the case.

Comment: Indeed, adding `( ::Int->Int->Int)` to the `(+)` of the original code makes the rest compile just fine.

Comment: It appears I oversimplified my example -- my apologies. I updated my post with an example where adding the type `:: b -> b -> b` to `(+)` (along with `-XScopedTypeVars` and an explicit forall) doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer, and for your clear explanation!